# what does a "git reset --hard origin" actually do?

Tags: git

A friend did a "git reset --hard origin" and after that pushed his changes. He did that instead of going "git reset --hard origin/branch_name" which is what he actually intended.

I think that all "git reset --hard origin" does is to reset your branches to exactly match all the related remote branches. However after his push I did a "git pull origin branch_name" and for some unknown reason to me, a bunch of new files were pulled that seemed to come from master (like if there was a merge from master); but in the local and remote logs we never see those files being committed or any merge from master to our branch, we just know that the issue occurred right after that push and have no idea what actually happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to reset the current branch to the state of the *default* (i.e. usually master) branch on `origin`.

Comment: I tend to disagree: `git reset` does not reach for remote, it merely parses the name of the revision parsed to it using the defined set of rules (see my answer). And after doing `git fetch origin` there will just be a bunch of refs under `.git/refs/remotes/origin` named after that remote's branches, no `HEAD` or something like this. And hence locally we don't know anything about what's currently the default branch at `origin`.

Answer (score 0):

That's an interesting question... The [`gitrevisions` manual page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) formally covers this (the `<refname>` case, point no. 5) but does not state what exactly happens if a `<refname>` is resolved this way.

I tried to do `git rev-parse origin` and Git tells me this revision is ambiguous (i.e. not found), and I do have `refs/remotes/origin` in the repo I used for testing.

Trying `git reset --hard origin` in that same repo with command execution tracing enabled (`GIT_TRACE=1` in the environment) resolves in the same failure of `git rev-parse`.

Hence my take on this is that your colleague (supposedly mistakenly) had a true local branch or a tag named "origin", and so `git reset --hard origin` actually reset their currently checked out branch to the tip commit of that local branch "origin".

I would now check this hypothesis by running `git branch -a` and `git tag` in their repo.

Comment: Thanks. I was informed that there is actually no branch called "origin" locally. Its not a remote branch, and if it got deleted locally would be hard to know. The main issue however remains, which is that a bunch of new files were pulled that seemed to come from master into our branch, and there was no merge. The funny thing is that the issue occurred right after the famous "git reset --hard origin" and his commit of a few files. Might be totally unrelated to the problem, but it's the only clue we've got.

Comment: I tried it locally and got this wheh doing "git status": # On branch my_branch
# Your branch and 'origin/my_branch' have diverged,
# and have 145 and 288 different commit(s) each, respectively. Seems after all that reset the current branch to master

Comment: @CarlosP, okay, I would then suggest to ask this question on the main Git mailing list (see [this](http://git-scm.com/community)) as this whole thread is ripe with "it seems"-s and "I suppose"-s, and it would be good to get an expert opinion.

Comment: I guess it has a bit of DWIMery (Do What I Mean) processing and has located a preferred origin branch on your local machine, or the preferred branch of a remote called origin. Note that in both cases it would be the commits that are available locally (e.g. those of the last fetch / push). Which version of git are you using.